# Máscara de telefone aplicada em Classe

Tags: javascript, html

Salve clan, estou apanhando com a função abaixo que funciona para ID, mas não consegui fazê-la se aplicar a classe, pois tenho muitos telefones. e apenas aplicada ao ID não me atenderia

(esta função não foi criada por mim, foi retirada aqui do forum mesmo)

```
<script>
 function mascaraFone(event) {
    var valor = document.getElementById("telefone").attributes[0].ownerElement['value'];
    var retorno = valor.replace(/\D/g, "");
    retorno = retorno.replace(/^0/, "");
    if (retorno.length > 10) {
      retorno = retorno.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{5})(\d{4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3");
    } else if (retorno.length > 5) {
      if (retorno.length == 6 && event.code == "Backspace") { 
        // necessário pois senão o "-" fica sempre voltando ao dar backspace
        return; 
      } 
      retorno = retorno.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{4})(\d{0,4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3");
    } else if (retorno.length > 2) {
      retorno = retorno.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{0,5})/, "($1) $2");
    } else {
      if (retorno.length != 0) {
        retorno = retorno.replace(/^(\d*)/, "($1");
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("telefone").attributes[0].ownerElement['value'] = retorno;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eu tenho uma função que utilizo a muito tempo que pode te ajudar. Ela serve para qualquer formato de mascara.

```js
isIE=document.all;
isNN=!document.all&&document.getElementById;
isN4=document.layers;
function mascara(campo, Mascara, evtKeyPress) {
    var i, nCount, Texto, tCampo, tMascara,bolMask, retTexto, codTecla;
    if(isIE) { // Internet Explorer
        codTecla = evtKeyPress.keyCode; }
    else if(isNN) { // Nestcape
        codTecla = evtKeyPress.which;
    };
    //console.log("cod tecla: "+codTecla);
    if (codTecla != 8 && codTecla != 0) { // backspace
        Texto = campo.value;
        // Limpa todos os caracteres de formatação que
        // já estiverem no campo.
        re = /[^A-Z0-9]/gi;
        Texto = Texto.toString().replace( re, "");
        tCampo = Texto.length;
        tMascara = Mascara.length;
        i = 0;
        nCount = 0;
        retTexto = "";
        tMascara = tCampo;

        while (i <= tMascara) {
            bolMask = ((Mascara.charAt(i) == ":") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == "-") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == ".") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == "/"));
            bolMask = bolMask || ((Mascara.charAt(i) == "(") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == ")") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == " "));
            if (bolMask) {
                retTexto += Mascara.charAt(i);
                tMascara++; 
            } else {
                retTexto += Texto.charAt(nCount);
                nCount++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        campo.value = retTexto;
        if (Mascara.charAt(i-1) == "9") { // so numero
            return ((codTecla > 47) && (codTecla < 58)); // números de 0 a 9
        } else { // livre
            return true;
        };

    } else {
        return true;
    };  
};
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return mascara(this,'(99) 999999999',event);" maxlength="14">
```

Espero ter ajudado. :)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado :D